# Getting IDs from t-SNE plot?

Tags: python, mapping

Quite simple, 
If I perform t-SNE in Python for high-dimensional data then I get 2 or 3 coordinates that reflect each new point. 
But how do I map these to the original IDs?

One way that I can think of is if the indices are kept fixed the entire time, then I can do:

1. Pick a point in t-SNE
2. See what row it was in t-SNE (e.g. index 7)
3. Go to original data and pick out row/index 7.

However, I don't know how to check if this actually works. My data is super high-dimensional and it is very hard to make sense of it with a normal "sanity check".

Thanks a lot!

Best,

Comment: Are you using some some package or tool to compute your t-SNEs? Or did you implement it from scratch yourself? If you implemented it yourself, then it is up to you to implement some way to track the data points from their original format to their embedded format.

Comment: I use sklearn.manifold import TSNE

Comment: @enumaris see above :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sklearn's t-SNE, then your assumption is correct. The ordering of the inputs match the ordering of the outputs. So if you do `y=TSNE(n_components=n).fit_transform(x)` then `y` and `x` will be in the same order so `y[7]` will be the embedding of `x[7]`. You can trust scikit-learn that this will be the case.